$C^n[0,1]\simeq C^m[0,1]$ as Banach algebras if and only if $m=n$
Prove that $C^n[0,1]\simeq C^m[0,1]$ as Banach algebras if and only if $m=n$.
I have proved that $C^n[0,1]$ is a Banach algebra, where the norm is defined as $$\|f\|=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\|f^{(k)}\|_\infty.$$
I think this is obvious by intuition, but because I cannot find a good basis in $C^n[0,1]$, I cannot think of a good way to prove this.
Suppose $n<m$, $\varphi:C^n[0,1]\to C^m[0,1]$ is a bijection and preserves the algebra structure and the norm, how to get a contradiction?

The case $n=0$, $m=1$ is solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736798/about-the-existence-of-an-isomorphism-of-algebras-between-the-algebras-of-math?rq=1

Does there even exist an isomorphism of Banach spaces? It is $C^1[0,1] \cong \mathbb{R}\oplus C^0 [0,1]$ as Banach spaces but I don't think that $\mathbb{R}\oplus C^0 [0,1] \cong C^0 [0,1]$?

There does not even exist a continuous algebra isomorphism (not just isometric). Indeed, assume to the contrary that $\varphi: C^n([0, 1]) \to C^m([0, 1])$, $n < m$, is a continuous algebra isomorphism. Let $C = \max\{1, \|\varphi^{-1}(x)\|_{C^n}\}$ and pick any function $f \in C^n([-C, C])$ whose restriction to $[0, 1]$ is not in $C^m([0, 1])$. Pick a sequence of polynomials $p_k$ s.t. $p_k \to f$ in $C^n([-C, C])$. Using chain rule and product rule, we see that,
$$p_k(\varphi^{-1}(x)) = p_k \circ [\varphi^{-1}(x)] \to f \circ [\varphi^{-1}(x)]$$
in $C^n([0, 1])$, where $p_k(\varphi^{-1}(x))$ denotes the application of a polynomial $p_k$ to the element $\varphi^{-1}(x)$ of an algebra. Then, as $\varphi$ is a continuous algebra homomorphism, we see that the sequence,
$$p_k = p_k(\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(x))) = \varphi(p_k(\varphi^{-1}(x)))$$
converges in $C^m([0, 1])$ (indeed, to $\varphi(f \circ [\varphi^{-1}(x)])$). However, $p_k \to f|_{[0, 1]}$ in $C^n([0, 1])$ and $f|_{[0, 1]} \notin C^m([0, 1])$, so $p_k$ does not converge in $C^m([0, 1])$, a contradiction.

I understand what you are proving, but I am still a little confused about some steps.  Could you please explain what is $x$ and why $p_k=p_k(\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(x)))$?

Maybe $x$ is the identity function $x \mapsto x$ and $p_k$ denotes $p_k(x)$.

@shwsq As Isllier said, $x$ denotes the identity function $x \mapsto x$ and applying any polynomial to the identity function gives that polynomial back.
